# How to publish latest revision langcode programmatically in each translation

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

1. My workflow is draft, publish and archived.
2. My translations are 'en(default)', 'fr', and 'de'.
3. My clients create a lot of nodes in draft status for their release.
4. We must release these latest revisions in these nodes.
5. Each nodes has some paragraph field.

I try the following code on drush eval, but "de" translations are changed as first revision in paragaraph field.

```
$langcode = "fr";
$nid = 12345;
// node loaded
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
if($node->hasTranslation($langcode)){
    // node storage
    $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($node->getEntityTypeId());
    // latest translation revision id
    $revision_id = $storage->getLatestTranslationAffectedRevisionId($nid, $langcode);
    $revision = $storage->loadRevision($revision_id);
    if($revision->hasTranslation($langcode)){
      $revision = $revision->getTranslation($langcode);
      $status = $revision->moderation_state->value;
      $is_draft = $status == "draft";
      if($is_draft){
        $revision->setNewRevision(TRUE);
        $revision->setRevisionCreationTime(REQUEST_TIME);
        $revision->set('moderation_state', 'published');
        $revision->save();
      }
    }
}
```

How to publish latest revision langcode programmatically in each translation.

Thanks.